# ASP.NET Core access to HttpContext in integration tests

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing

I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Testing.WebApplicationFactory<Startup>` in my integration tests. I'm trying to access `_fixture.Server.Host` property, but it's throwing an exception
*"The TestServer constructor was not called with a IWebHostBuilder so IWebHost is not available"*.

Could anyone tell, why is it so?
Here is my code:

```cs
public class OneTest:IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _fixture;
    public OneTest(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> fixture){
        _fixture=fixture;
    }
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestCanBeAuthenticated(){
        var host=_fixture.Server.Host; // Exception is being thrown
        // ... code ...
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial goal was to get access to `HttpContext`, so turned out that `TestServer.SendAsync(...)` returns `Task<HttpContext>` with all necessary properties like `Response`, `User` etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you check the TestServer class,you could found serval different constructors:

[image]

The error just indicates the server created by WebApplicationFactory doesn't contain  the instance of IWebHostBuilder in it's constructor

[image]

So,what's the purpose of accessing the host of TestServer in your test?

Comment: Hello, yes, I can understand this. My actual purpose is to access HttpContext in integration tests to test authentication mechanism. So how can I pass IWebHostBuilder to TestServer constructor when Test class inherits from IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory>?

Comment: @DanilPoletavkin - did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: @bbqchickenrobot - yes, method TestServer.SendAsync(...) returns Task<HttpContext>